# Android: Playing an Asset Sound Using WebView

Tags: android, audio, webview, android-assets

I am trying to play a sound from the assets folder when a user clicks on an  tag on my application's WebView. I found that I can use a new class extending WebViewClient to detect the extension of a link and if it is an mp3 file it can play it via the default Audio Player. But I want it to play within the activity without starting a new activity.

I used the following links as references:
[Sound in Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403271/sound-in-webview)
and [Error creating MediaPlayer with Uri or file in assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093562/error-creating-mediaplayer-with-uri-or-file-in-assets)

But it didn't work.

I tried using the following codes to do so:

```
package com.rangga.test.webview.sound;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    public MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        if(url.endsWith(".mp3")){
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(url);
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
            mp.start();

            return true;
        }else{
            return true;
        }


    }

}
```

I get an undefined method error on the getAssets(), I tried Googleing it and it says something about passing a Context. I am very new to Android and Object Oriented programming, so I am wondering if this the right way to do it and if there is a simple explanation on what a Context is. Thank you.

Below are my complete codes:

MainActivity.class

```
package com.rangga.test.webview.sound;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webMain;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webMain = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webMain);

        webMain.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webpages/test.html");
        webMain.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }


}
```

**EDIT**

So the codes works thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/488241/squonk but now another problem occurs, I updated the MyWebViewClient into the following:

```
package com.rangga.test.webview.sound;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    private Context context = null;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context c){
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        if(url.endsWith(".mp3")){

            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(url);
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                afd.close();
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return true;
        }else{
            return true;
        }   
    }
}
```

But I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException, the path seems right though. I've put 2 mp3 files in assets/webpages/sounds/1.mp3 and assets/webpages/1.mp3 and used the following html codes to test it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Audio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="file:///android_asset/webpages/sounds/1.mp3">File Asset</a><br/>
        <a href="1.mp3">Same Folder</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I get the following error on LogCat:

```
06-11 06:20:37.955: W/System.err(377): java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:///android_asset/webpages/1.mp3
06-11 06:20:37.966: W/System.err(377):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method)
06-11 06:20:37.974: W/System.err(377):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:314)
06-11 06:20:37.974: W/System.err(377):  at com.rangga.test.webview.sound.MyWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(MyWebViewClient.java:30)
06-11 06:20:37.985: W/System.err(377):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:193)
06-11 06:20:38.000: W/System.err(377):  at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:304)
06-11 06:20:38.005: W/System.err(377):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 06:20:38.005: W/System.err(377):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-11 06:20:38.014: W/System.err(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-11 06:20:38.014: W/System.err(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 06:20:38.024: W/System.err(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-11 06:20:38.024: W/System.err(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-11 06:20:38.024: W/System.err(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-11 06:20:38.054: W/System.err(377):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there something wrong with the way I called the file? Thanks before.

**SOLVED**

Thx to squonk's suggestions, I tried the following codes to make it work and it worked well, thank you squonk!

```
package com.rangga.test.webview.sound;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    private Context context = null;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context c){
        this.context = c;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        if(url.endsWith(".mp3")){
            url = url.replace("file:///android_asset/webpages/", "");
            Log.i("MyWebViewClient", url);
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(url);
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                afd.close();
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return true;
        }else{
            return true;
        }   
    }
}
```

And the html to test it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Audio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="webpages/1.mp3">File Asset</a><br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Though I did get an error if I repeatedly click it, but that's another question :D
How does one close one's question? >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you declare your `MediaPLayer` in `MyWebViewClient`, add the following...

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    private Context context = null; // Add this line

    ...
}
```

Then add a constructor to `MyWebViewClient` as follows...

```
public MyWebViewClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` get your assets as follows...

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(url);
```

In your `MainActivity` set the `WebViewClient` by passing `this` (which is the Activity `Context`) as follows...

```
webMain.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
```

Also you should return `false` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` if the url ends with '.mp3' - this shows your `WebView` is handling things and the 'host' application should not start an instance of the stock web browser.

**EDIT:** To play audio files from the assets directory, you need to set the data source differently - see the accepted answer to [play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289038/play-audio-file-from-the-assets-directory).

Also you should call `mp.prepare()` before calling `mp.start()`.

Comment: Wow, thanks it at least run now, you sir are legend.. wait for it.. dary! 

But when I click on link 1 and 3 it gets a java.oi.FileNotFoundException, it seems like the path on the link is wrong >.< while link 2 it just opens the webpage not available page.

Is there a way to play a sound in the asset file or should be in the raw file or sdcard?

Comment: @RanggaWiratno : See the EDIT at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yeah actually I tried the following too. I've added the parameters on the afd and added mp.prepare() and afd.close() before the mp.start() after reading this http://droidapp.co.uk/?p=272 but the weird thing is, I still get the java.io.FileNotFoundException even though the path is right. I tried messing around with the html but still can't get it right <a href="file:///android_asset/webpages/sounds/1.mp3">File Asset</a><br/> and <a href="1.mp3">Same Folder</a>. I've put 2 files to test it, in assets>webpages>1.mp3 and assets>webpages>sounds>1.mp3

Comment: I've edited my question, hope it helps you answering it, thanks again :D

Comment: @RanggaWiratno : To be honest, I can't put my finger on anything specifically. I would expect if you put `1.mp3` directly in the root of your `/res/assets` directory then the second URL (`<a href="1.mp3">Same Folder</a>`) should work. Perhaps start a new question linking the question I linked in my EDIT. It's not something I've done from a `WebView` before, sorry.

Comment: Yeah but unfortunately it didn't work either, I'll try testing with some other similiar projects. Ok then, thanks a lot hey :D

Comment: @RanggaWiratno : Try logging the `url` parameter being passed into `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` just to check that it looks the way you expect it. Also when you create `afd` in that method just try `...openFd("1.mp3");` as a test. Other than that, a new question with new eyes to look at it might help. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, will do when I get the time, currently a bit too busy for the next 3 days. Thanks again for the tips :)