# No sound playing MP3 from file in Android WebView

Tags: android, audio, webview, jplayer

I am having trouble playing local files with [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) in an Android WebView.

The audio files are located in: `src\main\assets\www\audio\`

HTML

```
<a href="audio/sound.mp3" class="sound">Method 1</a>
<a href="/assets/www/audio/sound.mp3" class="sound">Method 2</a>
<a href="/sounds/b.mp3" class="sound">Method 3</a>
<a href="http://example.com/sound.mp3" class="sound">This works</a>
<div id="jquery_jplayer"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
        swfPath: "scripts/",
        supplied: "mp3",
        solution:"flash,html",
        wmode: "window"
    });

    $('.sound').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#jquery_jplayer")
            .jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: this.href })
            .jPlayer("play");
    });
});
```

.java:

```
package com.example.myprogram;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class myprogram extends ActionBarActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myprogram_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // allow local storage
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myprogram, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

In `manifest.xml` I am only giving one permission which is for update checking:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is the error I get with Method 1 (see HTML above), and I get similar errors for the other methods:

```
/? E/﹕ Failed to open file '/android_asset/www/audio/sound.mp3'. (No such file or directory)
/com.example.myprogram E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
/com.example.myprogram E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I think that it's finding the file, because as soon as I change the a tags href to `incorrect/sound.mp3` I get a different error (below). Also I'm loading images with a src of `images/graphic.png` just fine.

```
com.example.myprogram E/AndroidProtocolHandler﹕ Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/incorrect/sound.mp3
```

Also loading a mp3 audio file off of a web server works fine as well.

**Update 1:**

I tried what was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966245/android-playing-an-asset-sound-using-webview?rq=1), but then I get this error:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/www/audio/sound.mp3. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.",
```

Comment: where your class name in .java?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh I edited the question with the full code.