# Load HTML content in Webview with case sensitive data

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a HTML file in `assets` folder of my project. And I load this file using webview as:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

every thing works good.

But in some cases if I put some data in html with different character case then it not works in default webview but works in device browser (E.g **Chrome**):

**E.g:** I am trying to play a audio file using html as:

`<html>
 .
 .
<audio id="mysound1" src="item/sounds/apple.mp3" autoplay></audio>
.
.
</html>`

But in `assets` folder I have file name as: `Apple.mp3`

If I load this html file in device browser then audio is playable, regardless there case in name. But if I try to load this html content in webview then this file is not playing. And I see a error in DDMS:

```
02-23 16:03:36.091: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(23303): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/item/sounds/apple.mp3
```

Can any one know about this behavior, how device browser load this file as there case in name is different. What should I do in webview to avoid this case sensitivity issue?

Comment: maybe insufficient privilages

Comment: @Kilanny How can I check, if there are any privileges issue?

Comment: Try to put your two files in sdcard and load it. Maybe the mp3 file is corrupt or unsupported to run by browser

Comment: mp3 file is OK. If I rename the file, then it also works in webview.

Comment: please check this SOLVED answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/10966245/1835231

Comment: @JatinPatel But I don't want to play that mp3 file with MediaPlayer. That file is working fine with webview. I just want to know why "apple.mp3" working and why not "Apple.mp3". As in device browser both are working.