# How to play audio on webview in android?

Tags: android

I want to play an audio from a URL on webview. I also want it to have play and pause button. I have tried opening the URL directly like this:-

```
myView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myView.loadUrl(myUrl);
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: better to put audio in ur asset folder in run in webview

Answer (score 6):

This can be done through Javascript Interface

**Create a Class WebInterface**

```
public class WebInterface{
    Context mContext;

    WebInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playSound(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void pauseSound(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**In your WebView class**

```
WebView browser;
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);   
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebInterface(this), "Android");        
browser.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");
```

**In HTML code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playSound(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }

    function pauseSound(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="playSound('Sound Played!')" />
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="pauseSound('Sound Paused!')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this answer negatived? It is the best workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Try, this is the working code,

```
 WebView mWebView;
 mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3");

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

i tried with one sample audio url. it should work.

Happy Coding..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Where you declare your MediaPLayer in MyWebViewClient, add the following...

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    private Context context = null; // Add this line

    ...
}
```

Then add a constructor to MyWebViewClient as follows...

```
public MyWebViewClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then in shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...) get your assets as follows...

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(url);
```

In your MainActivity set the WebViewClient by passing this (which is the Activity Context) as follows...

```
webMain.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
```

If you want more help please visit this link 
[Android: Playing an Asset Sound Using WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966245/android-playing-an-asset-sound-using-webview)

Answer (score 0):

What URL you want to play? If it is complex page with HTML5 content, you can use [crosswalk library](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html) and `XWalkView` instead of `WebView`. But this library will strongly increase your apk size.

Also you can try to set `WebViewClient` to your native `WebView` and handle [onLoadResource()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) method. If this method receives audio URL, direct it to the Android `MediaPlayer`.