# play html5 audio from android asset folder?

Tags: android

Hi I have developed an Android application which load Html5 file, that contains .mp3 files. The html files are stored inside the android asset folder. But when I try to load, the file is not playing. This is my path. `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/kids_sample/baba.mp3");`

Comment: post your webview client class with full code.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966245/android-playing-an-asset-sound-using-webview

Answer (score 1):

instead of loading audio files in `WebView`, load in `MediaPlayer` class.

and if you really want to load audio files in `webView`, then you have to code audio files in html file and load that html file in `WebView`.

example

```
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="kids_sample/baba.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but my file not only audio. i contains gif, text, images and audio. In this case how the MediaPlayer help us?

Comment: then code your file in html file and load that html file in webview

Comment: for images you can use <img src="kids_sample/baba.jpg" />
etc
and for so on. also check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks bro this is working. and i need some customization that i will handle. thankyou..

Comment: my pleasure bro. plz up vote and accept my answer .:)