# Using MediaPlayer (this, Uri.parse()) makes the application crash

Tags: android, parsing, uri, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make a media player on my android phone, but I have some issues with `Uri.parse()`.
I don't understand why my application is always crashing when I use Uri with Media Player.

But it works fine if I use a `R.raw.file` method.

**eg :**

*This works great*

```
//...
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song);
    mp.start();
//...
```

*This makes the app crash*

```
//...
    u = Uri.parse("file://android_asset/song.ogg");
    //What I use is a bit more complicated (see next commentary line), but it doesn't work with the previous line either
    //u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mp.start();
//...
```

Do you understand why the application is crashing everytime I'm using this, and could you explain to me please.

**Here is my Logcat:**

```
06-23 00:31:20.522  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-23 00:31:20.566  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations W/ResourceType﹕ Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
06-23 00:31:21.904  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
06-23 00:31:21.922  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
06-23 00:31:21.963  30428-30531/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
06-23 00:31:21.969  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
06-23 00:31:21.974  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
06-23 00:31:22.041  30428-30531/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
Build Date: 03/11/15 Wed
Local Branch: au016
Remote Branch:
Local Patches:
Reconstruct Branch:
06-23 00:31:22.042  30428-30531/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-23 00:31:22.056  30428-30531/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-23 00:31:22.195  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1f54ae44 time:40535044
06-23 00:31:47.625  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 64
06-23 00:31:47.625  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
06-23 00:31:47.626  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
06-23 00:31:49.954  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations time:40562803
06-23 00:31:50.066  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-23 00:31:50.067  30428-30428/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations, PID: 30428
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations/com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.arnaudsolente.claptrapcitations.Player.onCreate(Player.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)

        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)

        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)

            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)

            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)

            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)

            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat so it is easier to identify the problem. One thing i face on Linux, after file: i have to print three (/) slashes for uris. You may try to apply file:///android_asset/song.ogg (beside i never tried this way of accessing assets yet.)

Comment: I tried with three slashes but it doesn't work either :( I add my LogCat to my first post

Comment: You may have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093562/error-creating-mediaplayer-with-uri-or-file-in-assets . It goes further into identifying the problem so you could more easily find the solution.

Comment: Update... i found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876163/load-a-mediaplayer-from-a-uri-in-a-context-assets .it says that the native MediaPlayer is actually unable to load by Uri from assets. So you might use getAssets().open instead